# Determine a function based on the values and derivatives at different points

Tags: plotting, fitting

Googling didn't bring up anything useful for me, so I'm asking this question here.

Suppose that I have the value of a function at some points plus the derivatives at those points. Now I am looking for a Mathematica method that can give me a function that satisfies the data I have.

The data that I have are:

1. At $x=0, \qquad y=-1, \qquad \text{and} \qquad y'=1000$
2. At $x=0.5, \qquad y=0, \qquad \text{and} \qquad y'=0$
3. At $x=1, \qquad y=2, \qquad \text{and} \qquad y'=2000$

What I expect to have is something like the following graph,

[image]

As it is obvious, the derivative at the extremities is high and it is zero in the middle.

Comment: Have you considered using `Interpolation`? If you give us some of your data I will give you an example of how to use it. This will get you the graph and give you a function that you can use in all calculations.

Comment: @Hugh Please, check the provided data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First we put your data into the appropriate form

```
data = {
   {{0}, -1, 1000},
   {{0.5}, 0, 0},
   {{1}, 2, 2000}
   };
```

Now we make a function out of your data by interpolating

```
f = Interpolation[data];
```

Then we can use your function as we wish. First a plot

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As an example of how we can use it as a function, I include it in a differential equation

```
sol = NDSolve[{g'[x] == f[x], g[0] == 0}, g, {x, 0, 1}];
```

The result of this differential equation can be plotted as

```
Plot[Evaluate[g[x] /. First@sol], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can check that the function goes through your points by evaluating it and its derivative at your values of x

```
f[#] & /@ {0, 0.5, 1}
f'[#] & /@ {0, 0.5, 1}
```

> {-1., 0., 2.}
>
> {1000., 0., 2000.}

Have a look at the documentation for `Interpolation`. Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

The requirement to be smooth and to have extreme derivatives is difficult. Here is a function maker for you to play with.

```
ClearAll[makefunction];
SetAttributes[makefunction, HoldFirst];
makefunction[op_] := 
 DynamicModule[{pts = Table[{x, 0}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}], f, io = 1},
  Column[{
    Slider[
     Dynamic[io, (io = #; 
        f = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> io]) &], {1, 10, 
      1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"],
    LocatorPane[
     Dynamic[pts, (pts = #; pts[[1, 1]] = 0; pts[[-1, 1]] = 1; 
        f = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> io]) &],
     Dynamic@
      Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, 
       ImageSize -> 11 72]],
    Button["Output data", op = pts, ImageSize -> 2 72]
    }]
  ]
```

You need to give it a variable into which you can put the data when you are happy with it. The slider controls the interpolation order; with 1 it is linear the usual smoothness used is 3.

makefunction[data1]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
As you can see I have pushed the locators around until they look about right. However, if we now make this smooth by moving the slider to 2 we get

[image: Mathematica graphics]
So you can see we need to adjust further. I will leave that to you. When you are happy with your function you can press output and then the data will be in whatever variable you used. Then you can make an interpolation function to use elsewhere. You may wish to play with the number of points or even specify the derivative at various points. I will leave that for you to embellish.

```
f = Interpolation[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps you can appreciate the difficulty of making a smooth function with large derivatives. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Msen - Note that the derivative of the data is not required to be known for all data points. For example,

`f = Interpolation[{{{0}, -1, 1000}, {{0.5}, 0, 0}, {{0.75}, -50}, {{1}, 2, 
     2000}}];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, the graph is far away from what I expect to have. I have included the graph that I would like to have.

Comment: Interpolation puts a cubic polynomial through the data points and ensures smoothness at each point. I think you need more points on the graphs to make things work as you wish.  Do you have more information?

Comment: Is this more of a "how can I construct a function that looks like a mental picture" problem? In your picture you certainly don't have zero gradient at x = 0.

Comment: Sure I don't have zero gradient at x=zero. According to the data that I provided the gradient is 1000 at x=0.

Comment: Sorry I meant in the middle at x =0.5 you have zero gradient in your data but you have drawn a definite gradient in your plot.

Comment: Now you are completely right. Sorry! I edited the pic.